# Scala Dispatch REST GET example

Tags: scala, rest, scala-dispatch

I have a client that makes a REST call to a server that exposes REST API's. Here is what I have so far implemented:

```
  override def getData[T](reqURL: String, requestParam: Option[Seq[(String, String)]])(responseHandler: T => Unit) = {

    val onSuccess: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
      case s => responseHandler(s.asInstanceOf[T])
    }
    val onFailure: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
      case e => e.printStackTrace
    }

    val request = requestParam match {
      case Some(params) => url(reqURL).as_!("user", "pass") <<? params
      case None         => url(reqURL).as_!("user", "pass")
    }
    Http(request OK as.String).onSuccess(onSuccess).onFailure(onFailure)
  }
```

It works perfectly fine, but what I noticed is that the HTTP connection is open even after the call is complete. How can I close this connection? I might want to do it after the onSuccess or onFailure call has happened. Any suggestions?